# Is there a setting for VBA to ignore type mismatch errors?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have just come to realise that, on the majority of computers, VBA will ignore the so-called type mismatch error, Error 13.

However, just now I have come across a PC that does not ignore type mismatch errors.  So, my question is:

Is there a setting somewhere that I can use to stop my computer from ignoring type mismatch errors?

Examples of a type mismatch error that seems to be generally ignored, but not on this one PC.

```
?msgbox (1,,22)
?Application.Version = 12#
```

Appreciate any insights on this - including, what is the best way to find code that does have a type mismatch but still compiles and runs on most systems?

Comment: Do you actually get a "Type mismatch" error, or are you just saying you get something which appears to be a type mismatch error.  I ask because neither of your examples should cause a type mismatch - the `Msgbox` should happily cast the integers to strings (and, after displaying the MsgBox the `?` would display the return value), and the `Application.Version = 12#` should compare the Version with 12# (I'm not sure whether it would cast the Version to a double, or cast the 12# to a string, but both are valid) and return a True or False which would then be displayed by the `?`.

Comment: On which versions of Office are you seeing the success and failure of those statements?

Comment: Hi... the Application.Version example is real.  Both PC are running Win 10 with Office 2010.  VBA was running in MS Word. My PC returns False for the Application.Version example, the other PC actually throws Error 13, Type Miss match

Comment: (a) Did the `MsgBox` display and then the "Type mismatch" error occur when it tried to `Print` the return value, or did the "Type Mismatch" error occur when trying to invoke the `MsgBox`?  (b) You have tagged the question as excel-vba - does that mean that you have confirmed that the same issue exists in Excel?

Comment: Hi I don't have physical access to the PC. The actual error occurred with Application.Version and the error happened in code and in the immediate window. I tagged excel-vba because not as many people use word-vba.  The msgbox example was more of an illustration of the issue, I have not and am unable to access the problem PC again :-(  thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone stumbles across this. I was unable to find a way / setting to ignore type-mismatch - I was thinking there might be some sort of Option EnforceTypesStrictly, but apparently not.

In the end I had to rewrite the offending code explicitly cast the variables in question to their appropriate type: e.g. using cStr, cLng etc.

I don't know why this 1 particular PC threw errors, but it did.

Fixed now.

Comment: *VBA will ignore the so-called type mismatch error, Error 13.*  This is not even remotely close to true -- in fact the opposite is true as @YowE3k mentions in the comments above. Because of implicit type conversion, neither of the example codes should cause an error on *any* computer. So, VBA is not "ignoring an error" on computers where no error occurs, because there is (or should be) no error to ignore. The problem lies elsewhere on the problem PC, unfortunately. I'm glad you are able to solve the problem for your immediate needs, though :)

Comment: I take your point @DavidZemens but it *was* the VBA IDE that spat out Error 13 and called it a type mismatch, it would be my guess that if there were no implicit conversion then an error would occur... so for some reason... possibly because there was no implicit conversion (but perhaps something else) - unfortunately it will remain a mystery.  Thanks, I'm glad too.  The explicit type casting of the revised code does not result in the 'not an error because that is technically wrong' Error 13. ;-)